# Have upper and lower bars in theorems identical to lstlisting

Tags: thmtools

I would like to have a style for theorems identical to lstlisting with  `frame=lines` but I could not find a option for 
declaretheorem to do so. Going away from thmtools is not easy as I have already plenty of other theorems (in different styles).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{listings}

\declaretheorem[style=definition,numbered=no,shaded={rulecolor=Black,rulewidth=0.5pt,margin=0.5em,bgcolor={rgb}{1,1,1}}]{theorem}
\lstset{frame=lines}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
Test
\end{lstlisting}
\begin{theorem}
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

Yields:
[image: problem]

I would like to have the "Theorem." in the same box as "Test" and still use declaretheorem (as I need it for many different styles).

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very easy to obtain with `ntheorem` (which cooperates with `thmtools`, but isn't required here):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[thmmarks, amsmath]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{frame=lines}%

\theoremstyle{nonumberplain}
\theoremprework{\bigskip\hrule}
\theorempostwork{\vspace*{-0.35ex}\hrule}
\theoremindent=0.5em
\theoremrightindent=0.5em
\theoremheaderfont{\upshape\bfseries}
\theoremseparator{.}
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\vspace*{1cm}
\begin{lstlisting}
Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test.
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{theorem}
  Blah blah. Blah blah. Blah blah. Blah blah. Blah blah. Blah blah. Blah blah. Blah blah.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it is a beautiful solution but it seems like I have a package conflict with amsthm vs. ntheorem. (Errors are " LaTeX Error: Command \theoremstyle already defined." or "Package ntheorem Error: Theorem style plain already defined.", depending on the order)

Comment: That's right.  You have to choose between `amsthm` and `ntheorem`. Note the latter has an `amsthm` option, which predefines  the same layout as amsthm. Also, one superiority of `ntheorem` is its automatic placement of the end-of-proof  symbol (even when the proof in question ends up with a mulitline equation).

Comment: Thank you, switching to ntheorem helped (with the initial problem asked here) and it was quickly done (even though I have nearly a dozen of theoremstyles: the conversion is really straight forward).